# How to use UICollectionViewController in storyboard while still supporting ios 5.1?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

It is a best practice to detect if a certain feature's class exists and degrade user's features depending on availability. I created UICollectionView in storyboard and a standard tableview to support ios 5.1 users. I then simply check if the user has this feature and segue to the appropriate scene. However, when I now try to compile my code I get a "dyld: Symbol not found: _UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader" This seems very anti-pattern of apple to not allow ios6.0 features in storyboard with a ios 5.1 deployment target.

```
if ([UICollectionView class]) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"UserShow" sender:self];
} else {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"UserShowTable" sender:self];
}
```

The above seems like a pretty reasonable approach to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. As soon as you drop the collections view controller to the storyboard, it will try to reference it automatically, what will result in the compilation error you've got.

Comment: lame, but i'm guessing you can still everything programmatically?

Comment: yes, you can instantiate it programmatically. However its a pure nightmare in this case. :)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is not proper to put only link answers but her it is not possible to include the whole files.

Please see [this](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView).

A controller is designed to provide the same functionality as UICollectionController of iOS 6 but still supports to iOS 4/5

What developer is telling

> PSTCollectionView
>  Open Source, 100% API compatible replacement of
>   UICollectionView for iOS4.3+
>
> You want to use UICollectionView, but still need to support iOS4/5?
>   Then you'll gonna love this project. I've originally written it for
>   [PSPDFKit](http://pspdfkit.com/), my iOS PDF framework that supports text selection and
>   annotations, but this project seemed way to useful for others to to
>   keep it for myself :) Plus, I would love the influx of new gridviews
>   to stop. Better just write layout managers and build on a great
>   codebase.
>
> The goal is to use PSTCollectionView on iOS 4/5 as a fallback and
>   switch to UICollectionView on iOS6. We even use certain runtime tricks
>   to create UICollectionView at runtime for older versions of iOS.
>   Ideally, you just link the files and everything works on older
>   systems. Practically, it's not that easy, and especially when you're
>   using subclasses of UICollectionView-classes, since they can't be
>   replaced at runtime.

Comment: If you're going to recommend `PSTCollectionView`, please recommend steipete's original repo, as he's actively maintaining it: https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView

Comment: It's just forking of it. The real source is the same as you mentioned. Means if any one try to refer the link actually referring the link you provided. Anyway I am changing the link to the original repo. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: PSTCollectionView was a breeze, thanks for the recommendation. I just replaced my UICollectionView classes references and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

There's no compatibility solution for pre-6.0 deployment via storyboards, but [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView) does support iOS 5.0+ and is actively maintained. It does work at runtime to use `UICollectionView*` on 6.0 and later, and should be storyboard compatible.

Comment: To follow up on this answer: I recently worked on an iPad application that used PSTCollectionView for iOS 5.1+ support for UICollectionView, and it worked quite well.