# iOS 5.1 crashes when using collections view

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, ios6

I am trying to use collection view and I want to support 5.1. I am not using story board. I have added collectionview to my view controller. I am identifying the version and opening collection view if its 6.0 or higher else opening another view controller. When I run my application in 5.1 it immediately crashes with error :

> Symbol not found: _UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader

I have seen the link below it only describes the case when you use story board.
[How to use UICollectionViewController in storyboard while still supporting ios 5.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176494/how-to-use-uicollectionviewcontroller-in-storyboard-while-still-supporting-ios-5)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you've set your deployment target to iOS 5.1 in your app target in your project?

That should cause the following:

"...Framework APIs that are unavailable in earlier versions will be weak-linked..."

(from the quick help of `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`).

If it's crashing immediately upon launch, it sounds like it's not being weak-linked.

If you're sure you've set a deployment target of iOS 5.1, you could try forcing the entire UIKit.framework to be weak-linked to troubleshoot the issue. To do that, you mark it as Optional as opposed to Required in the Linked Frameworks and Libraries section:

[image]

FWIW, I've been able to successfully do what you're describing in a Mac OS X application: I have an app built against the latest SDK, and at runtime, check the version of OS X and load different nibs. In the nibs for later versions of OS X, I can make use of UI elements that did not exist in earlier versions of OS X. Provided your app is nib-based, I can't see why you wouldn't be able to do the same in iOS. (Note that if you're using storyboards, that's a different story).

Here's an example project of how to set it up:

http://www.markdouma.com/developer/CollectionViewFinagler.zip

Comment: My deployment target is actually 5.0

Comment: I saw the example in the link above, My code is pretty similar to the example just that I am using header view extra. I am using if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 6.0) to determine the iOS version. Even didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in appdelegate is not being fired before the app is crashing. Any idea why?

Comment: When I removed header in the collection view it is working flawlessly any idea?

Answer (score 3):

UICollectionView is not supported in iOS5. You can only use it with iOS6 apps. Sorry, but you are out of luck with it.

[Here](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView) is an open source project that should help you out though, as it is defined:

> Open Source, 100% API compatible replacement of UICollectionView for
>   iOS4.3+

Comment: He or she already stated that they were aware that `UICollectionView` is only available in iOS 6.0 and later: "I am identifying the version and opening collection view if its 6.0 or higher else opening another view controller." Provided the project is set up properly with 5.1 deployment target, there should be no immediate crash: `UICollectionView` can be used in 6.0 and later, and something else for earlier...

Comment: @NSGod I never said that you could not use CollectionView for 6.0 and something else for 5.1. I even provided a link to something they could use for pre-6.0 versions.

Comment: If you are already using `PSTCollectionView` and see this error then you might have accidentally used the string `UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader`. Instead, you should use `PSTCollectionElementKindSectionHeader`.